# Slide Menu with Navigation Drawer + Tabs + ListViews

Tags: android, fragment, android-fragmentactivity, android-listfragment

I would like to have a UI like google play store, which has a slide menu + tabs + listviews.

I need to make an e-commerce app that opens to a menu using `navigation drawer`. The entries of the menu need to have different type of fragments like `Fragment`, `ListFragment`. i'll try to explain better.

Suppose i click on the "Home" menu entry of the menu then i need to open a page(Fragment?) that has 2 tabs (buy - sell). must they be `ListViews` or `ListFragments`?. once i select an entry of the list then i get a detail page.

How do i manage all this? Im guessing that there is some imcompatability with navigation drawer tabs and ListView/ListFragment?

Please tell me hoes this is all done or show me a sample ot tutorial? thanks

Comment: Hi, have u got any solution yet??need the same in my project

Answer (score 1):

The two tabs you are talking about should be `listviews`. And what you are asking for is implementing viewpager and navigation drawer in the same layout, which is possible but seems very odd to have the both of them in the same place if you ask me.

Links:

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/android-tutorial-using-the-viewpager.html
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: thaks for the links. i've already used the 2,3 link you posted and im trying to put them together without success. as to the other part of your post, tha it seems odd, how else would u do this? considering that i need a menu and that i need the 2 tabs (only for some menu entries) and that these 2 tabs are lisviews?

Comment: Instead of making a viewpager just for the buy,sell i would look to see if it it possible to actually show a subentry of buy/sell under the home entry(when it is clicked) in the navigation drawer itself